# Should the Host header always required in HTTP Proxy CONNECT requests?

Tags: http, proxy, request, http-proxy

Based on [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/CONNECT), an HTTP CONNECT request can have a `Host` and an `Proxy-Authorization` header.

```
CONNECT server.example.com:80 HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: server.example.com:80\r\n
Proxy-Authorization: basic aGVsbG86d29ybGQ=\r\n\r\n
```

The `Proxy-Authorization` header is optional.

Is the `Host` header *also* optional, and should we (as a proxy server) accept a request as follows without the additional lines of headers?

```
CONNECT server.example.com:443 HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RFC 2616 states](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-14.23) in Section 14.23:

> ```
> A client MUST include a Host header field in all HTTP/1.1 request messages .
> ```

A CONNECT request is an HTTP request. Therefore, as long as the request line specifies HTTP/1.1, the Host header is mandatory even in CONNECT requests. If you want to strictly comply with the standard, your proxy server should not accept HTTP/1.1 requests without this header.